# ElasticSearch get fields even if they are empty or null

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have the following elasticsearch terms filter for a sample dataset.

```
"filter":{
   "type":"and",
   "and":[
      {
         "type":"terms",
         "terms":{
            "field":"car_registration_no.raw",
            "terms":[
               "61123",
               "61124",
               "61125"
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

and the following is the sample result :

```
{
    "result": [
      {
        "totalHits": 3,
        "hits": [
          {
            "schemaid": "adef89sesdceasjkmn5dlky6djj7kk189lkdqsc",
            "localVersion": 2,
            "row": {
              "primaryKey": {
                "car_registration_no": "61123"
              },
              "columns": {
                "model": "Nissan",
                "submodel": "Saloon",
                "date_used": 1597017600000
              },
              "editsVersion": 0
            },
            "highlight": {}
          },
          {
            "schemaid": "adef89sesdceasjkmn5dlky6djj7kk189lkdqsc",
            "localVersion": 2,
            "row": {
              "primaryKey": {
                "car_registration_no": "61124"
              },
              "columns": {
                "model": "Nissan",
                "submodel": "Saloon",
                "accidents": "1",
                "accident_date": "12/12/2019",
                "date_used": 1597017600000
              },
              "editsVersion": 0
            },
            "highlight": {}
          },
          {
            "schemaid": "adef89sesdceasjkmn5dlky6djj7kk189lkdqsc",
            "localVersion": 2,
            "row": {
              "primaryKey": {
                "car_registration_no": "61125"
              },
              "columns": {
                "model": "Nissan",
                "submodel": "Saloon",
                "date_used": 1597017600000
              },
              "editsVersion": 0
            },
            "highlight": {}
          }
        ],
        "counts": {},
        "nextToken": null
      }
    ]
  }
```

Only one car, car no 61124 has accidents recorded against it, how can i retrive null or blank values for the others?

I have aleady referred to [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_dealing_with_null_values.html) but since i am a beginner at this, i am not able to understand how to handle it.
so the expected result would be that i want to see the empty fields **accidents** and **accident_date** to appear as null or blank if they have no value, in the above example, car_registration no 61123 and 61125 have null values and therefore i want to retrieve all fields irrespective of blank values.

```
{
    "result": [
      {
        "totalHits": 3,
        "hits": [
          {
            "schemaid": "adef89sesdceasjkmn5dlky6djj7kk189lkdqsc",
            "localVersion": 2,
            "row": {
              "primaryKey": {
                "car_registration_no": "61123"
              },
              "columns": {
                "model": "Nissan",
                "submodel": "Saloon",
                "accidents": "null",
                "accident_date": "null",
                "date_used": 1597017600000
              },
              "editsVersion": 0
            },
            "highlight": {}
          },
          {
            "schemaid": "adef89sesdceasjkmn5dlky6djj7kk189lkdqsc",
            "localVersion": 2,
            "row": {
              "primaryKey": {
                "car_registration_no": "61124"
              },
              "columns": {
                "model": "Nissan",
                "submodel": "Saloon",
                "accidents": "1",
                "accident_date": "12/12/2019",
                "date_used": 1597017600000
              },
              "editsVersion": 0
            },
            "highlight": {}
          },
          {
            "schemaid": "adef89sesdceasjkmn5dlky6djj7kk189lkdqsc",
            "localVersion": 2,
            "row": {
              "primaryKey": {
                "car_registration_no": "61125"
              },
              "columns": {
                "model": "Nissan",
                "submodel": "Saloon",
                "accidents": "null",
                "accident_date": "null",
                "date_used": 1597017600000
              },
              "editsVersion": 0
            },
            "highlight": {}
          }
        ],
        "counts": {},
        "nextToken": null
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: your use case is not quite clear. Can you please explain your expected result?

Comment: @Bhavya, I have updated my question to reflect how i want the data to see, i want to see the fields that have null values as well that is the result to retrieve all fields for each primaryKey

Comment: please go through my answer and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: @SS_flair, you should follow the official doc https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/null-value.html for handing null values

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja thank you for the quick reply, since i don't have access to the mapping of the dataset, i'll have to look at generating the fields dynamically on the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you want is to be able to see the `NULL` values of your documents, which is not possible by default as `NULL` values are not indexed and searchable, please refer [official NULL_VALUES doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/null-value.html) for more info

> A null value cannot be indexed or searched. When a field is set to
> null, (or an empty array or an array of null values) it is treated as
> though that field has no values.

But to achieve your use-case, you need to provide the `null_value` param in your mapping and while indexing the documents, if you receive no value than pass the `null_value` param value in your doc as shown in below complete example

**Index mapping**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "accidents": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "null_value": "NULL" --> note this
            },
            "accidents_date": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "null_value": "NULL"
            },
            "car_registration_no" :{
                "type" : "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index sample doc**

```
{
    "accidents" : "1",
    "accidents_date": "12/12/2019",
    "car_registration_no" : "61124"
}
{
    "accidents" : "null",
    "accidents_date": "null",
    "car_registration_no" : "61125"
}
{
    "accidents" : "null",
    "accidents_date": "null",
    "car_registration_no" : "61123"
}
```

**Search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "terms": {
            "car_registration_no": [
                "61124",
                "61123",
                "61125"
            ],
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    }
}
```

**And expected search result**

```
  "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "carindex",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "accidents": "null", --> note this
                    "accidents_date": "NULL",
                    "car_registration_no": "61123"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "carindex",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "accidents": "1",
                    "accidents_date": "12/12/2019",
                    "car_registration_no": "61124"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "carindex",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "car_registration_no": "61125"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can use [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/query-dsl-terms-query.html) that returns documents that contain one
> or more exact terms in a provided field.

Adding a working example with search query and search result(using the same sample index data as provided in the question)

**Search Query: (Version 7.*)**

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "row.primaryKey.car_registration_no": [ "61125","61123", "61124" ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
{
  "took": 16,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64398592",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "schemaid": "adef89sesdceasjkmn5dlky6djj7kk189lkdqsc",
          "localVersion": 2,
          "row": {
            "primaryKey": {
              "car_registration_no": "61123"
            },
            "columns": {
              "model": "Nissan",
              "submodel": "Saloon",
              "accidents": "null",
              "accident_date": "null",         <-- note this
              "date_used": 1597017600000
            },
            "editsVersion": 0
          },
          "highlight": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64398592",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "schemaid": "adef89sesdceasjkmn5dlky6djj7kk189lkdqsc",
          "localVersion": 2,
          "row": {
            "primaryKey": {
              "car_registration_no": "61124"
            },
            "columns": {
              "model": "Nissan",
              "submodel": "Saloon",
              "accidents": "1",
              "accident_date": "12/12/2019",
              "date_used": 1597017600000            <-- note this
            },
            "editsVersion": 0
          },
          "highlight": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64398592",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "schemaid": "adef89sesdceasjkmn5dlky6djj7kk189lkdqsc",
          "localVersion": 2,
          "row": {
            "primaryKey": {
              "car_registration_no": "61125"
            },
            "columns": {
              "model": "Nissan",
              "submodel": "Saloon",
              "accidents": "null",
              "accident_date": "null",           <-- note this
              "date_used": 1597017600000
            },
            "editsVersion": 0
          },
          "highlight": {}
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**If you are using Version 5.*, then please go through this documentation on [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-terms-query.html), to know its syntax.**

Comment: the terms query  i am making a POST with the filter query, do i replace the filter query parameter with query parameter?